# How to reach downvoters after improving my post and ask for review again to remove downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I have posted a question on one week back. After that I have received down votes. Below is the link to the (now deleted) question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379743/why-http-protocol-is-choosen-by-web

Hence I have gone through the FAQs and formatted the question properly. Then I have requested the user who down voted my question to revert back through the comment section. Since I didn't get any response from the user, I have flagged the question and requested the moderators to review the question again. My sole intention here is to find out whether the question still needs improvement. If yes what are those? If not, remove those down votes. I didn't get any response from any moderator also.

I presume down votes represent criticism on my post which suggests to improve the post. Based on the information available at the referred links in SO, I did my best to improve the quality of my post. Now the question is not eligible to down votes. How to reach down-voters and ask them "I have improved my post. If you agree please remove the down votes. If not please help me with the reasons for down vote and hence I will improve my post further"?

PS: My account is banned from posting questions. I learned from Meta Stack Overflow that down votes are one of the reasons and address the reasons for down vote and remove those.

I am sorry if this question has been already discussed and addressed in some other posts. I have searched for answers on SO before posting this question. If you know any posts which answers my questions posted in this thread completely, please help me with the links.

Comment: Most people actually *don't* want to improve, but will rather tell the stupid downvoter how wrong *he* is. If you try to leave comments with your downvotes, you will soon see how unproductive that is.

Comment: @Bo Persson, certain extent I agree with you. How ever what about serious authors. It should not become obstacle for serious authors who really try to improve. It would be better down vote with out explanation should not cost reputation and should not eligible to take any action on the account.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I have gone through the link that you have specified. I feel that myquestion is not duplicate. My question is all about When ever author feels his question is good enough and not eligible for down votes, how to know the reason for downvote to improve his post. If there is no justifiable reason for down votes how to revert back the down vote. And there is a suggestion to enforce the comments along with down-vote. How ever as respecting to your action I have removed my suggestion. Can you please go through the question carefully once again and reopen it.

Comment: @Tim Post: I have gone through the link that you have specified. I feel that myquestion is not duplicate. My question is all about When ever author feels his question is good enough and not eligible for down votes, how to know the reason for downvote to improve his post. If there is no justifiable reason for down votes how to revert back the down vote. And there is a suggestion to enforce the comments along with down-vote. How ever as respecting to your action I have removed my suggestion. Can you please go through the question carefully once again and reopen it.

Comment: @users who down voted this question, Can you kindly let me know the reason for it. So that I will improve the question further more. Thanks in advance. By the way I have modified the question and improved the question. Please revert down votes if you agree with me that question is now good, clear and shows research effort

Comment: to [quote Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156362/why-was-my-question-about-a-library-recommendation-closed-as-not-a-real-questio): "Folks this is a new user, doing exactly what we hope new users do by coming here to find out what went wrong with a question. Do we really need a down vote pile up?"

Answer (score 8):

Voting is anonymous and unless the downvoter chooses to post a comment explaining their downvote there is absolutely no way you can find out why they downvoted your post.

That said, if you hover over the downvote arrow the tooltip reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

...and your question does *not* show much research effort, this is just a guess but that's probably why you got downvoted. Your question discusses a variety of protocols that are quite different, and you just throw them in there, it's blatantly obvious that you didn't do your homework. Had you done some minimal prior research you would have found out, for example, that your assumption that HTTP is equivalent to TCP, POP, SMTP, and SOAP is false.

Just reading the relevant Wikipedia articles would be enough to clear some, if not all, of the confusion in your question. I'm fully aware that Wikipedia sometimes is inaccurate, but it's more than adequate for basic stuff like that and since I'm working with those protocols every day for the past 10+ years, I'm very confident that the relevant articles are quite well written. The actual answer to your question can be found in the [History section of the World Wide Web article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web#History), and Stack Overflow is really *not* the place for questions that can be answered so easily.

I'm sorry but I can't see how your question could be improved. This all may sound a bit harsh to you, but you should keep in mind that you are asking volunteers for free help. It's not unreasonable for us to require you to do some minor research on your own before resorting to Stack Overflow.

Further reading:

- Stack Overflow's [How to Ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask),
- Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx),
- Eric Raymond's [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and
- Matt Gemmell's [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Please read them all *very carefully*, and apply the advice given in your current and future questions.

Comment: @Yannis, Thanks for your explanation and your answer. This answer is helpful for me. How ever take the below scenario. I have post a question which not that qualitative. How ever I have been modified by spending some effort and modified as specified in the above articles. Now the question is good enough and at-least not eligible to down vote. So having down votes on good post is absurd. How can the author asks the down voters for review and get removed those down votes. That is all about my question

Comment: @Ramesh You come to Meta and ask people to review your question. Simple, isn't it? All you want is feedback, and you can get feedback from everyone, why _must_ it be from the people that downvoted your question? Just leave all that stuff about downvoting out of it... Be warned though that if you haven't _really_ put some effort in your question, asking on Meta _may_ lead to more downvotes.

Comment: Just one more to throw in the ring: http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/