# Why was my question about a library recommendation closed as "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

This is regarding this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483054/string-length-to-pixel-length

I assume that it got closed because nobody knows of a Lua library that deals with pixels. But that does not mean it doesn't exist. Now it's closed, others are prevented from answering the question.

On Stack Overflow there are many questions asking the very same thing, just not for Lua:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pixel+length

for the most part these questions get answered and left open for the community to answer as the community as a whole will almost always know of more ways than a small group of users.

As a new poster it's quite disheartening to see that a question you post gets immediately voted down and closed. To be fair the question was very short but did not at the time include the pixel size or font type as that is a variable that the end user determines and is clearly a factor that the library or dll requested would find out.

Such a library does exist and can be found here:

http://wiki.inspired-lua.org/platform.withGC

but it's not for Windows so based on the fact that what I asked has been done already on other platforms its not unreasonable in my view to ask this community if they know a way to achieve the same results on windows.

Comment: I suspect you are making some assumptions of your own here.

Comment: If you've already found a library that does what you want, you just want an equivalent for another platform, why on earth isn't that included in your original question? Your question was closed because it is "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered". Including an example that does what you need on another platform would have immediately made it clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Folks this is a new user, doing exactly what we hope new users do by coming here to find out what went wrong with a question. Do we _really_ need a down vote pile up?

Comment: @TimPost I guess it would help if the question title was not "Assumptions by 'experts'." That _"experts"_ could sound a little offensive for somebody.

Comment: @TimPost Though a fair point (and I certainly hope the OP stays around for a while) the tone of the question is not all that great. "Experts" in inverted commas and some of the assumptions Martijn Pieters hints at don't help. This be teh intarwebs and it does not take much to set people off. To the OP I would say, just put this initial experience behind you. Learn from it what there is to learn and your next experience will be much better because of it. Don't be too discouraged.

Answer (score 20):

This is the opening line of the question:

> Can anyone recommend any compiled libraries or other method in Lua for getting the pixel length from a given string.

This makes it not constructive or even off topic as it's a shopping recommendation. (Just because something is free doesn't stop it being a shopping recommendation).

If you'd simply asked:

> How can I get the pixel length of a string?

then the question *might* have stayed open and even got some answers.

Comment: Wow, +7 and -2 in less than 2 minutes, thanks for the reply but this place is very uninviting so Im out of here.

Comment: @Mike Downvotes here on Meta often indicate disagreement as stated in the Meta FAQ. In this case they might simply mean disagreement with your assumption that there's nothing wrong with your question. Don't take downvotes here personally. Nor those on SO itself. They are not to ridicule you, but to inform you there's something wrong with your question. You received good comments there. And Meta rep doesn't mean a thing to begin with. Chris' answer is just fine and should help you along. A bumpy start perhaps, but get to know how things work here and you'll be just fine.